# error- declaration is incomplete or malformed

Tags: sql, oracle, function, types

I have the error- the declaration of ... is incomplete or malformed coming from the last type- "Subscriber_T" but I don't see a problem with the syntax. These are the scripts:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Surnames_T AS OBJECT (
  Surname varchar (20)
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE listSurnames_T 
AS Varray(4) of Surnames_T;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE listTels as object(
  Tel   number (12)
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE listTels_T as Varray(5) of listTels;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ADDRESS_T AS OBJECT (
  NUM       number (6),
  STREET    varchar (20),
  TOWN      varchar (20)
);
/

CREATE or replace type TAddress 
as table of Address_T;
/

create or replace type Subscriber_T as object(
  num_s  number(6),
  sName varchar(30), 
  surname listSurnames_T,
  Adds TAddress,
  DateOfBirth  date,
  member function cal_Age return number,
  phoneNo   listTels_T
);
/
show error
```

I need a fix please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put member functions after all other fields; you can't sneak a field in at the end:

```
create or replace type Subscriber_T as object(
  num_s  number(6),
  sName varchar(30), 
  surname listSurnames_T,
  Adds TAddress,
  DateOfBirth  date,
  phoneNo   listTels_T,
  member function cal_Age return number
);
/

TYPE SUBSCRIBER_T compiled
```

Obligatory [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0192c6).

This is shown in [the syntax diagram in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_type.htm#LNPLS1620); you can have one or more attributes, and then one or more elements (including functions), but you can't mix them around. Notice which bits have loops, and where they loop back to.

Comment: Thanks Alex! The type compiles successfully now, but i have a new problem after i create the table of Subscriber_T type. I have just posted a new question that includes this table along with the function & insert values. Please, help. Tnx